# Getting AdWords customerId without a refresh token

Tags: asp.net, authentication, google-ads-api

I'm working on a Web Application that allows user to connect AdWords account.
1) So once user connected their AW account I am getting token from AW API that includes an access token and a refresh token. So far so good, it's just a typical OAuth2 process.

2) Next time another user connects same AW account, AW would not provide me with a refresh token, assuming I have it stored somewhere, which is expected.

So here is the problem, there doesn't seem to be a way to get user information without the refresh token, meaning I can't identify the user to retrieve the refresh token.

I'm using .NET library (`Google.Apis.Analytics.v3`) and it doesn't allow me to request customer information without providing the refresh token...

Here is the sample code:

```
var tokenResponse = await adWordsService.ExchangeCodeForTokenAsync(code, redirectUri);
var adWordsUser = adWordsService.GetAdWordsUser();
var customerService = (CustomerService)adWordsUser.GetService(AdWordsService.v201502.CustomerService);
var customer = customerService.get();
```

`adWordsService` is just a wrapper around the API. 
so when I execute this line `var customer = customerService.get()` I get a following error:

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: AdWords API requires a developer token. If you don't have one, you can refer to the instructions at https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/signingup to get one.
>
> Google.Api.Ads.AdWords.Lib.AdWordsSoapClient.InitForCall(String methodName, Object[] parameters)

Developer token is there and so are all the client IDs.

If I add this line `adWordsUser.Config.AuthToken = tokenResponse.AccessToken;` before making the call, it complains about the refresh token.

> ArgumentNullException: Value cannot be null.
>
> Parameter name: Looks like your application is not configured to use OAuth2 properly. Required OAuth2 parameter RefreshToken is missing. You may run Common\Utils\OAuth2TokenGenerator.cs to generate a default OAuth2 configuration.
>
> Google.Api.Ads.Common.Lib.OAuth2ProviderBase.ValidateOAuth2Parameter(String propertyName, String propertyValue)

So the question is, how does one acquire user information (in this case `customerId`, according to this article https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/guides/optimizing-oauth2-requests#authenticating_multiple_accounts) during authentication for the purpose of storing the refresh token?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I just found the problem is in the `adWordsService`. When the `AdWordsUser` is created it isn't assigned the updated authentication provider which contains the latest authentication token. Once this authentication provider is added the `AdWordsUser` doesn't try to refresh the token since the token hasn't expired yet, thus there is no need for the refresh token.